# Perl: Nothing happens when I run "perl" from the command line

Tags: perl

If I run `perl` by itself from the linux command line, nothing happens. I see the cursor move down a line and if I enter `print "Hello, world";`, still nothing happens. Is there anything I can input from the command line from here? I know that you can run `perl -e 'print "Hello, world"';` and how to create a perl script. Just wondering why running `perl` by itself does nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type the following:

```
$ perl
print "Hello World\n";
Ctrl-D
Hello World
$
```

That's last line is you holding down the Control key and pressing `D`. Not typing *Ctrl-D*.

If you type `stty -a`, you'll see that Ctrl-D is he EOF character. That's Perl reading in a file from STDIN. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4):

On my system (Windows, cmd shell) if I just type `perl` it starts to read code from STDIN, and when I hit end of file Ctrl-Z, it executes the code. As demonstrated here:

```
C:\perl>perl
$a = "asd";
print "\$a = '$a'";
^Z
$a = 'asd'
C:\perl>perl
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper [ 3.14 ];
^Z
$VAR1 = [
          '3.14'
        ];
```

This is handy, because normally I can't use double quotes in the cmd shell without quoting issues.

Answer (score 3):

Run `perl` by itself in Linux command line, `perl` will wait for your input, as exampled by the answer given by @david-w

If you want a interactive Perl environment, you can start perl in debugging mode by `perl -d -e 42`, or install [Perl Shell(psh)](http://gnp.github.io/psh/).

Run `perldoc perlrun` and `perldoc perldebug` for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
perl -e "print 'Hello World';"
```

Otherwise, just entering perl doesn't really do anything. (That I know of, mines does the same as yours)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for perl shell.. aka PSH

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/psh/doc/psh.pod